# Adding META tag to nodes with a specific topic

Tags: 7, meta-tags

If a node has a term reference to a specific term (say termid 123) I want to add this META tag to prevent search engine spiders from indexing the page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Is [hook_page_build()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) the right hook for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you definitely could use `hook_page_build()` (it would work), but since that hook is really intended for use with page.tpl.php, and meta tags are outputted in html.tpl.php, I think it might not be the 'Drupal' way.

Another option might be to use [`hook_html_head_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7), which allows you to alter the `<head>` tags before they're rendered:

```
function MYMODULE_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $tid = function_to_get_term_id();
    $related_tids = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_FIELD_NAME');

    if (!empty($related_tids) && $related_tids[0]['tid'] == $tid) {
      $head_elements['MYMODULE_meta_robots'] = array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'name' => 'robots',
          'content' => 'noindex'
        )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

You might also want to look at adding `rel="nofollow"` attributes on the links to those node in teaser displays, it might help speed up the process a bit.

Comment: thanks Clive, that's awesome! I like the rel="nofollow" ideas as well!!!